# How can I find from which key the timeout signal sent from Qtimer objects in Qmap comes from?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qt-signals, sender, qtimer

In a function, how to understand the signal sent from Qtimer objects that I created in Qmap, how to find from which object the signal comes from in the slot function.

I created Qmap above  code
SQL.h

```
public slots:
 void experiment();
 void run();
private:
 QMap<QString,QTimer*> job;
```

I create QMap value and key with Qtimer.
SQL.cpp

```
void SQL::experiment()
{
  QTimer *timer=new Qtimer();
   
  job.insert("dd",timer);

  QTimer *timer1=new Qtimer();
  job.insert("ss",timer1);
 
  job.value("dd")->start();
  job.value("dd")->setInterval)(5000);


  job.value("ss")->start();
  job.value("ss")->setInterval)(10000);

  connect(job.value("dd"),SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(run()));
  connect(job.value("ss"),SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(run()));

}
```

In this slot, how can I understand which of the Qtimer in the Qmap receives a signal at that time?

```
void SQL::run()
{
  //job.value(key)  // how to understand key

}
```

I thought I could use sender() with Qmapiterator, but I couldn't find out how. can you help?

Comment: Why don't you use `setObjectName()` for each `QTimer` and then ask for it with `sender().objectName()` instead of using this map?

Comment: how to use your method, you can give me examples code

Comment: ı will write many timer

Comment: Each `QObject` (so also `QTimer`) can have an object name. This can be set with `QObject::setObjectName()` and get `QObject::objectName()`. It is really handy feature, you should use it instead of some complicated maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old way is using `QSignalMapper`. You could also set the key as dynamic property of the timer object, so you could access it through `QObject::sender()`. But, today you should probably just use a lambda.

First, change the run slot to take any parameters you want:

```
void SQL::run(const QString &key)
{
    QTimer *timer = job.value(key);
}
```

Then, just use lambda to easily pass the required parameters

```
QString name="ff";
connect(job.value(name), &QTimer::timeout, this, [this, name]() { 
            run(name); 
        });
        // name is capture by value above,
        // so changing name variable later does not
        // affect the value captured by the lambda
```

---

As a side note, you shouldn't use the old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros unless you really have to for some reason. Use the "new" (10 years old) connect syntax.

Comment: how can i change dd name to dynamic, When ı write QString name="ff";  connect(job.value("dd"), &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]() { 
            run(name); 
        });   this error, how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Mahmut Depends on what you mean by "dynamic". I edit the answer a bit, avoiding the repetition of the map key.

Comment: I recommend you spend a day studying C++ lambdas, it's quite a broad subject. Especially learn about capturing by reference vs capturing by value, and the special meaning of capturing `this`.

Comment: this is error, 'name'  cannot be implicity captured because no default mode has been specified

Comment: Did you remember to add `name` to the capture list? You'd get that error, if you didn't specify default capture mode, and didn't specify explicit capture.

Comment: how can ı specify this

Comment: @Mahmut It's in the answer already, in the `[this, name]`. That captures both `this` and `name` by value.